# Warning: unrecognized #pragma

Tags: c++, eclipse, iar

Recently I've installed the IAR embedded workbench for Eclipse Luna. I've used Eclipse before, so I'm somewhat familiar with the layout and different functions the IDE has to offer.

(partially off-topic) I used to compile using GNU CC, along with DS-5 for Eclipse, specifically for the Renesas processor line-up. Our software departement wanted to change the compiler, however. That's why we've chosen IAR. Everything compiled well before changing the compiler at that time.

When I compile my software right now, it returns me a warning: `Warning[Pe161]: unrecognized #pragma`. I've never seen this warning before. Have I overlooked something during the install of the IAR plug-in for Eclipse, or am I something missing here? This could probably help in getting rid of some annoying errors too which appear in the same source file later on.

```
/* Transfer source buffer : allocated to L1 cache disabled area in large-capacity on-chip RAM space */
//#ifdef __CC_ARM
#pragma arm section zidata = "BSS_DMAC_SAMPLE_INTERNAL_RAM"
static uint8_t dmac_src_data_internalram_1[DMAC_BUFF_SIZE_4096];
static uint8_t dmac_src_data_internalram_2[DMAC_BUFF_SIZE_1024];
static uint8_t dmac_src_data_internalram_3[DMAC_BUFF_SIZE_256];
#pragma arm section zidata
//#endif
#ifdef __ICCARM__
static uint8_t dmac_src_data_internalram_1[DMAC_BUFF_SIZE_4096] @ "BSS_DMAC_SAMPLE_INTERNAL_RAM";
static uint8_t dmac_src_data_internalram_2[DMAC_BUFF_SIZE_1024] @ "BSS_DMAC_SAMPLE_INTERNAL_RAM";
static uint8_t dmac_src_data_internalram_3[DMAC_BUFF_SIZE_256]  @ "BSS_DMAC_SAMPLE_INTERNAL_RAM";
#endif
```

I'm sure the brains at stackoverflow will come to an aid in this one ;)

Comment: Might be nice to see the #pragma line of code

Comment: added to OP. The warning occurs on the very first apprear of the `#pragma`.  The 3 lines under `#ifdef __ICCARM__` give an error that the statics have already been declared above. Might this be related?

Comment: Can't find `#pragma arm ...` in the developer guide.  http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf

Comment: 1st `#ifdef` is commented out so double defn.

Comment: Thanks.. I really overlooked that one..

Answer (score 0):

*[it's way after the event but I'm writing a summarised answer here for the benefit of people finding this question]*

GCC uses the "section" pragma to put declarations in different regions of memory; IAR uses a proprietary "@" syntax extension as you can see in the two blocks of declarations in your example, which are equivalent.

As one of the commenters pointed out, your problem is that the GCC version is being seen by IAR because the #ifdef guarding it has been commented out.